# iPhone Application Uploading On Apple Store

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning

I am new in iPhone world, I have register to iPhone Dev program today and I have to upload applications on App Store. But I don't know how to install certificate and upload applications on iTune Store can anyone briefly explain the steps for installing certificates and uploading the applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iphone Development guide
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've registered, you will have access to the Program Portal, which has instructions for setting up all the certificates and uploading to the store.